# Assign values to hidden fields in jQuery with dynamic id?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, web

Ok, so i got this table. This table are dynamically generated through a loop from backend. like so:

```
<%int iterator = 0;    
for(Iterator it = pd.getEntries().iterator();it.hasNext();){
   EntryData entry = (EntryData)it.next();
%>
<tr>
   <td><div id="oldvalue1_<%=iterator%>" class="editable_select"><%=entry.getIdentifiertype()%></div></td>
   <td><input type="hidden" id="newValue1_<%=iterator%>" value=""></td>
   <td></td>
   <td><div id="oldvalue2_<%=iterator%>" class="editable"" ><%=entry.getIdentifier()%></div>
   <input type="hidden" id="newValue2_<%=iterator%>" value=""></td>
   <td></td>  
</tr>
<% iterator++;} %>
```

What i want to accomplish on this table are "edit-in-place", sort of...I got this function in jQuery that turns the oldvalue1_* into a select-box, like so:

```
$(window).load(function(){
var clickFunction = function(){
 var id = $(this).attr("id");
 var smallId = id.substr(10);//yeah, this is a temporary hack...
 var select = '<select name="select" id="select" onChange="THIS IS WHAT I NEED">';
 var options = ["ITEMNUMBER", "GROUP", "ALLITEMS"];
  for(var i = 0; i < options.length;i++)
    select += '<option value="'+options[i]+'">'+options[i]+'</option>';
    select += '</select>';
    $(this).html(select);
    $(this).unbind('click',clickFunction);
}
$("div.editable_select").bind('click',clickFunction);
});
```

what i would love to get help with is to use the onChange to pass the new, selectet value to a hidden. i sorta got the right mindset here, i think: onChange="$("#newValue1_"+smallId).value($(this).val());">
But the amount of "s and 's is killing me, it just wont work. So, what should i do?

I also got this for the other table-element:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("div.editable").click(function(){
    var newInput = "<input type ='text' class='newInput' value=\""+$(this).text()+"\">";
    $(this).html(newInput);
    var id = $(this).attr("id");    
    $("input.newInput").focus();
    $("input.newInput").keydown(function(event){
    if(event.which == 13){  
       var lastDigit = id.substr(10);//Yeah...
       var valNumber = id.substr(8);//These are ugly, im working on it so don't hate on me  :P
       var value = $(this).val();
       $(this).parent().text(value);
       if(valNumber == 2){
        var changedtext = $("#editable2_"+lastdigit).val();//This right
        $("newValue2_"+lastDigit).val(changedtext);// here wont work
       }
    }
   });
});
```

Here too are my problem passing the values to their hidden-fields. I checked with the alert-function that i got the values to the var's, it's just that last bit that i'm missing.
I will appreciate all help, i really need it here. And, keep in mind that i'm a total n00b in jQuery so answers like "you should use the .[insert function name] " wont help much.

Thanks a bunch! <3
(i don't know how to get the funky colours in the code, i'm sorry)

Answer (score 1):

Can't just be matter of a missing # in your last line?

```
$("#newValue2_"+lastDigit).val(changedtext);
```

instead of

```
$("newValue2_"+lastDigit).val(changedtext);// here wont work
```

Comment: That was just a typo from my part, but no: im afraid it's not that simple. ty anyways.

Comment: Cool, let's take a deeper look then :)

Answer (score 1):

You were REALLY close with this.

```
onChange="$("#newValue1_"+smallId).value($(this).val());">
```

What you need to remember is to use one set of quotes for the onchange holder and another for any content inside. So...

```
<select name="dothis" onChange="$('#newValue1_'+smallId+'').val($(this).val());">
```

Should work. I did a fiddle just to make sure. http://jsfiddle.net/MatthewDavis/Rb3cs/

Edit: I see what you're seeing about the generated line. I updated the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/MatthewDavis/Rb3cs/1/ and stripped the double quotes inside the variable that creates the select and replaced them with the xml representations.

Seems to work. Have at it.

Edit of my edit: Also, for anyone who needs the help but doesn't want to look at the fiddle, here's the line where the select is defined.

```
var select = "<select name=&quot;dothis&quot; onChange=&quot;$('#newValue1_'+smallId+'').val($(this).val());&quot;><option value='one'>1</option><option value='two'>2</option><option value='three'>3</option></select>";
```

Comment: This is a good start. The problem i get is that the select is generatet thorugh a string:      var select = '<select>'; so the outer ' are causing trouble. Do you know a way around it.

Comment: Added edits that will hopefully get where you need to be. I know how flustrating <-- my word, you can't have it... the quotes stuff can be. Just need to think of them as Russian nested dolls.

Comment: Tanx, i'll try this out. looks promising :)